# Gitlab does not automatically run post-receive hook

Tags: gitlab, githooks

Gitlab is hosted locally on my server. When I push a commit, the post-receive hook doesn't work. I made the owner of the hook `git:git` and made it executable. When I execute the file manually, it works.

Comment: owner should be current user but the important thing is to make it executable using `chmod 755`.

Comment: I already made file executable

Answer (score 1):

GitLab will execute the custom `post-receive` as long as it's placed in the repo's `custom_hooks` directory and both the directory and file are owned by `git`. Also, make sure your hook is expecting input on stdin, not via standard args - I say this since you mentioned running the script manually and it worked.

Unfortunately custom `post-receive` errors are not as easy to debug. A `pre-receive` error would be sent back to the client. I suggest adding lots of your own logging in your hook so you can see exactly what's happening. Put the first log directly after the shebang so you know your hook got executed.

The docs at https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/administration/custom_hooks.html#custom-git-hooks have helpful steps, if you haven't already seen them.